# How do I get an array with all elements with the same key?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
<?php
array ( 
0 => array ( 'name' => 'id', 'type' => 'integer', 'null' => 'NO', ), 
1 => array ( 'name' => 'strasse', 'type' => 'string', 'null' => 'YES', ), 
#...
)
```

How do I get an array with all the names or with only all the types?

like:

```
array('id','name',...)
```

Comment: So you would like to obtain the "name" field of each entry of the first array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP 5.5 you can use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$names = array_column($array, 'name');

// array('id','strasse',...)
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for. So there is no solution without a loop through the array to generate the new array before PHP 5.5?

Comment: Correct. It's simple enough but this does make it much easier to do.

Comment: [Here is a workaround for PHP 5.4](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/7368/Polyfill-for-the-PHP-5-4-array_column%28%29-) with `if(!function_exists("array_column")){....`